# Four columns, changing order depending on width with media queries

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a solution using our friend javascript, but I'm wondering if you CSS gurus might have a more elegant solution for me.

I have four columns like so

```
| A | B | C | D|
```

When they start getting a bit cramped, around 1130px wide on the screen, I want to change it to this order:

```
| B | C | D |
|     A     |
```

The next stage on compressing them would be:

```
| B | C |
| A | D |
```

Then for more mobile layout:

```
| C |
| B |
| D |
| A |
```

I know it's kinda on the crazy side, but there's good reason for it. The columns are essentially for different task stages. So it's nice to see certain categories first when it comes to looking at a project overview.

I dont have an issue personally moving the divs around with some jQuery, but it would be nice to code it using CSS.

Comment: You might try using relative/absolute positioning on sections, and change the top and/or top-margin property based on the media query. This is easier with fixed height content, but you could tell each to start where you want it on the page based on the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the height of your columns, it might get a bit tricky, but you can use a combination of css media queries (such as `@media screen and (max-width:1130px){...`) and absolute positioning to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zHJ4f/2/) to get you started. Just resize the width of your browser to trigger the break points (set arbitrarily at 700, 500 and 300 pixel widths).

You still may need the javascript (or jQuery) to set the `top` values of some of your columns based on heights of other columns, though.

Comment: Very interesting model. I have to admit when i first started learning responsive design i mostly stuck with width percentages, never thought to use positioning percentages.

Answer (score 2):

[Twitter Bootstrap 3's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is pretty powerful, and could probably get what you wanted.

it would be something like this using their classes (I would use their mixin's with less to create it, it keeps your classes more semantic).  See [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbSVq/4/)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-6">C</div>
        <div id="b" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-0">B</div>
        <div id="d" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-0 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-3">D</div>
        <div id="a" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-12 col-md-pull-0 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:
Using their built in LESS Mixins for some bonus points... This could probably be grouped a bit better, but I think its easier to read with each item as an individual.

```
#a{
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-pull(6);
    .make-md-column(12);
    .make-md-column-pull(0);
    .make-lg-column(3);
    .make-lg-column-pull(9);
}

#b{
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-pull(6);
    .make-md-column(4);
    .make-md-column-pull(4);
    .make-lg-column(3);
    .make-lg-column-pull(0);
}

#c{
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-push(6);
    .make-md-column(4);
    .make-md-column-push(4);
    .make-lg-column(3);
    .make-lg-column-push(6);
}

#d {
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(6);
    .make-sm-column-push(6);
    .make-md-column(4);
    .make-md-column-push(0);
    .make-lg-column(3);
    .make-lg-column-push(3);
}
```

then your HTML is just:

```
<div id="c">C</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="d">D</div>
<div id="a">A</div>
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO its Twitter Bootstrap 3's response grid classes.  Its even better if you used your LESS mixins.  I'll update what that would be in a min, although I can't test it.

Comment: That's pretty crazy stuff. I need to look at TB3 some more. We're using version 2 on this project actually, but I'll see if i can get it integrated. I like beercodebeer's solution too as it is a simple standalone implementation.

Comment: Yea, I just started using TB3, and their new grid system is really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple solution is to duplicate the content, and then hide or show divs depending on screen width. So your markup might look like this:

```
<div id="container-desktop">
    <div class="col">A</div>
    <div class="col">B</div>
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
</div>

<div id="container-tablet">
    <div class="col">B</div>
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col">A</div>
</div>

<div id="container-phone">
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">B</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col">A</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
#container-tablet,
#container-phone {
    display:none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {

    .col { width:50% }

    #container-desktop {
        display:none;
    }

}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {

    .col { width:100% }

    #container-tablet {
        display:none;
    }

}
```